# SQL Calculate cumulative total based on rows within the same table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate a cumulative total for a field for each row in a table.

Consider a number of passengers on a bus, I know how many people get on & off at each stop, but i need to add to this the load on the bus, arriving at each stop.

I've got as far as getting a field which will calculate how the load changes at each stop, but how do I get the load from the stop before it? note, there are a number of trips within the same table, so for Stop 1 on a new trip, the load would be zero.

I've tried searching, but being new to this, I'm not even sure what i should be looking for and the results I do get I'm not even sure are relevant!

```
SELECT [Tripnumber], [Stop], Sum([Boarders] - [Alighters]) AS LoadChange
FROM table 
Group By [Tripnumber], [Stop], [Boarders], [Alighters]
Order By [Tripnumber], [Stop]
```

Comment: Mysql? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT [Tripnumber], [Stop],
       Sum([Boarders] - [Alighters]) OVER (PARTITION BY tripnumber ORDER BY Stop) As LoadChange
FROM table;
```

I don't think the `GROUP BY` is necessary.